# `static_assert` on `std::initializer_list<T>::size` in a function

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, initializer-list, static-assert

In my unit tests, I want a quick and (cleanish) dirty way to assign values to a static-size C-array from an `initializer_list`. I'm not a complete beast, so I want to `static_assert` that the sizes are the same. I wrote a helper function `set_array` to do this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void set_array(T (&x)[N], std::initializer_list<T>&& list) {
  assert(list.size() == N); // why can't I static_assert in C++17?
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    x[i] = list.begin()[i];
}
```

with the intention of using it as `set_array(foo, {1, 2, 3, 4});` with foo declared like `int foo[4]`.

I'm using C++17, so `std std::initializer_list<T>::size` is constexpr, but as soon as I pass the list through a function call, I lose the privilege of treating it as constexpr since I can't constrain the function parameters to be constexpr.

This feels like it should have a simple solution that I'm not seeing. Sure, I could imagine some perverse metaprogramming games I could play to encode the size in a type, but this is a simple little helper that's supposed to make things clean and readable, and I don't want to go nuts.

**Question:** Is there a simple solution, or should I just live with the runtime assert? (Yes, I know that if I'm given a simple solution, I'm going to feel stupid for not having seen it myself.) Think I'm going about it the wrong way? That's fine, I'm open to suggestions and appreciate the criticism.

**Details:**
For completeness, here is the compiler error and version info. In Clang version 8.0.0-3 (That comes with Ubuntu clang-8) I get:

```
error: static_assert expression is not an
      integral constant expression
  static_assert(list.size() == N);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And with GCC 8.3.0 I get a similar error, additionally telling me that `list` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails even though `size` is `constexpr` is because `list` is **not** a constexpr variable so any member function calls on it will also not be `constexpr`.

All is not lost though.  What you can do is use a `std::array` instead of a `std::initializer_list` which lets you even get rid of the `static_assert` like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void set_array(T (&x)[N], std::array<T, N>&& list) {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    x[i] = list[i];
}                                                          

int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
    int arr[4];
    set_array(arr, {1,2,3,4});
    std::cout << arr[3];
}
```

If you tried using

```
set_array(arr, {1,2,3,4,5});
```

then you would get a compiler error like

```
main.cpp:12:16: note: candidate function [with T = int, N = 4] not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'std::array<int, 4UL>'
constexpr void set_array(T (&x)[N], std::array<T, N>&& list) {
```

Comment: Not sure if I am right, but it seems that this function will be executed during the program runtime, not during compilation.  If this is the case then why declare it as constexpr?

Comment: @shargors having it be `constexpr` doesn't cause any harm, and may allow the compiler to perform a stronger optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to functions are not constants.

This is legal in C++:

```
void foo( bool which ) {
  std::initializer_list<int> a = {1,2,3};
  std::initializer_list<int> b = {1,2,3,4};
  int x[4];
  std::initializer_list<int> c = which?a:b;    
  set_array(x, c);
}
```

try this:

```
template<class T>
struct block_deduction_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>
using block_deduction = typename block_deduction_t<T>::type;

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void set_array(T (&x)[N], block_deduction<T const(&)[N]> list) {
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      x[i] = list[i];
}
```

now this permits you to *omit* trailing elements, but they will be zero-initialized.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06ee3df194d88df7).

Then again, this solution:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void set_array(T (&x)[N], T const(&list)[N]) {
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      x[i] = list[i];
}
```

actually blocks under-sized right hand sides.  So might be better.

Syntax exactly matches yours.

If you want a pretty error message, and for the right hand types to be converted to match the left hand side types:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
constexpr void set_array(T (&x)[N], block_deduction<T> const(&list)[M]) {
   static_assert(M==N, "wrong number of elements");
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      x[i] = list[i];
}
```

there are many variants.

Comment: What are block_deduction_t and block_deduction templates for?  What is the name of this technique?

Comment: @shargors It is called blocking deduction.  And they block deduction.  Basically they prevent the C++ language from using the 2nd argument to determine what the template arguments are.  So `set_array( some_int_array, {3.14} )` works because it isn't confused by `double` vs `int`.

Comment: I think you meant the other way around:
set_array( some_double_array, {3} )
, right?

Comment: I like this solution and I wanted to thank you personally for your answer because I did gain from it. I hesitated to accept the alternative, but I ended up just using std::array as an intermediate for shear simplicity—I sided with the minimal code footprint. But your solution is also very useful to me.